# If coaxial is half duplex, how come it's that fast?

Tags: duplex

I have heard coaxial cables operates in half duplex. If thats the case, how come I get 500 mbps using a cable modem&router? Is the duplex just not that important? Or did I miss something?

Comment: "_I have heard coaxial cables operates in half duplex._" That was true for the original ethernet, but modern protocols using coax are full duplex. Your cable service does _not_ use ethernet on the WAN (coax), only on the LAN (UTP).

Comment: @RonMaupin Yep. I remember my old MediaOne connection. Cable downstream but phone line for upstream. Fancy stuff back then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Fast" is very relative. The common DOCSIS variants support up to 10 Gbit/s downstream and 6 Gbit/s upstream in full duplex using *frequency-division duplex* (different frequencies for upstream and downstream). Consumer-grade G.hn supports up to 2 Gbit/s.

Half-duplex with CSMA/CD was used with obsolete 10 Mbit/s Ethernet over coax (10BASE5 and 10BASE2). Ethernet has long since shifted to twisted-pair copper cabling (up to 40 Gbit/s) and fiber (up to 400 Gbit/s currently, 800 and 1600 Gbit/s under development), all full duplex.

Comment: So is it true that Ethernet over Coax is full-duplex by using different frequencies for upstream and downstream?

Comment: Depending on the exact protocol in use, it may be full duplex.

Comment: Can you give me further reading material? I'm talking about the technology itself, like the line coding technique, modulation used, and such (for encoding over coax). I wanna really know how the physical layer works and how it sends bits as electrical waves. I learned a bit about how it works in LAN ( for example Manchester coding) but not the latest technology. Thanks. I really wanna get to the details of how it works.

Comment: You can find the offical physical-layer specifications for G.hn at https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.9960 and DOCSIS 4.0 at https://www.cablelabs.com/specifications/CM-SP-SECv4.) - note that resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

Coaxial cables are good for a connection between 2 devices, in this way its pretty fast, not due to being half duplex or full duplex, if not to its inner characteristics. Half duplex, most of times, consists of two ways, one for uplink and the other one for downlink

Comment: Coax cables can be (or at least were) used with multiple access methods (see my answer) and could in theory be used with FDM schemes as well.